# How are ServiceBusReceivers managed by ServiceBusTriggers

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, .net-6.0, azure-servicebus-topics

Following the [best practices for reuse of Service Bus factories and clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2#reusing-factories-and-clients), the reuse of `ServiceBusReceiver` is recommended. [This great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71144000/17269112) for another question shows how a factory with such receivers can be implemented, which is then meant to be used as a singleton. However, I can't seem to find details of how this can be used together with a `ServiceBusTrigger`. Can this be done?

I guess my question stems from a limited understanding of how the `ServiceBusTrigger` is actually triggered, and how the [different parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#usage) of a trigger can be bound. I.e. does the trigger somehow create and use `ServiceBusReceiver` under the hood? Any additional insight into this area is greatly appreciated!

Using the in-process worker for .Net 6, for a project with multiple `ServiceBusTriggers`

Comment: It will be helpful to go thru the [code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension) of Azure Function on how it provides `trigger` function for Service Bus messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trigger creates and manages the `ServiceBusClient` and any senders/receivers that are used.  Since the trigger is already handing messages to your function, normally, you wouldn't need to bind to the receiver directly for use in the body of the function; for message settlement and related activities, you'd make use of the `ServiceBusMessageActions` as demonstrated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/overview/azure/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus-readme#message-settlement).

I don't believe that it is currently possible to bind directly to a `ServiceBusReceiver` via the trigger; it appears we redirect that to the message actions implicitly *([src](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus/src/Triggers/ServiceBusTriggerBindingStrategy.cs#L57))* - but I haven't tried to verify that.

Comment: That clear things up! Regarding the binding of `ServiceBusReceiver`, it makes sense to use the message actions, I got it mixed up with the older `MessageReceiver`, which doesn't seem to have its equivalents described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#additional-types) for the newer versions. I might go ahead and raise an issue in azure-docs for this if it doesn't already exist. 

Thank you for the answer and great work you put in!

Comment: I fell into the same trap :) This was a very helpful answer. Thank you!